# How to make a slideshow banner in html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slideshow

I want to make my banner changed automatically just like a slideshow. The banner I took from a folder and it can read all banner in that folder and display it on a website automatically changes. I already make it to read all banner and display it on the website, but it kind of random image, not changed except if I reload the page. This the code:

```
<?php 
     $imglist=''; 
     //$img_folder is the variable that holds the path to the banner images. 
     // see that you dont forget about the "/" at the end 
     $img_folder = "images/"; 
     mt_srand( (double)microtime()*1000 ); 
     //use the directory class 
     $imgs = dir($img_folder); 
     //read all files from the directory, checks if are images and ads them to a list (see below how to display flash banners) 
     while ( $file = $imgs->read() ) 
     { 
         if (eregi("gif", $file) || eregi("jpg", $file) || eregi("png", $file))
          $imglist .= "$file "; 
     } 
     closedir($imgs->handle); 
     //put all images into an array 
     $imglist = explode(" ", $imglist); $no = sizeof($imglist)-2; 
    //generate a random number between 0 and the number of images 
     $random = mt_rand(0, $no); $image = $imglist[$random]; 
    //display image 
    echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$img_folder.$image.'" border=0>'; 
?>
```

And how to make that PHP into HTML? if I change the extention into html, the banner div show the code not the images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The psuedocode for what you're doing would go something like:

load images from a directory into an array
on page load select a random image from image array
display first image
every X seconds display another image from image array

to display properly, your php file needs to be loaded/served from a web server. To do this, deploy your php file to your web server and then test it out.

an example of a banner I created a few years agao, that is similar to what you are after, [is here](http://minkewhaleproject.org)

Answer (score 0):

First, make your PHP echo out a hidden `<input>` element, with value containing the JSON string of image paths.  Using your code, something like:

```
<?php

    $out = " /*  Beginning of your page code */  "

    $imgJSON = json_encode($imglist);
    $out .= '<input id="bans" type="hidden" value="' .$imgJSON. '" />';

    $out .= " /*  Rest of your page code */  "

    echo $out;
    die();
```

Then, you can use the example below to swap the images in the banner div.  I demonstrate a very simple animation, just to show how it is done.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e95wLy1r/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<!--  Not req if you echoed out a hidden input via PHP: 
<input type="hidden" id="bans" value='["300/49","300/51","297/50","298/51"]' />
-->
<div id="banner"></div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var i = $('#bans').val();

var j = JSON.parse(i);
var max = j.length - 1;
var cnt = 0;

var timerId = null;
function swapBannersTimer() {
    doSwap();
    timerId = setTimeout(swapBannersTimer, 3000);
}
function doSwap(){
    var str = 'http://placekitten.com/' + j[cnt];
    $('#banner')
        .html('<img class="far_right" src="'+str+'" />')
        .promise()
        .done(function(){
            $('img').animate({
                marginLeft: '0px'
            },500);
        });
    cnt = (cnt < max) ? cnt+1 : 0;
}
swapBannersTimer();
```

**CSS:*

```
#banner{width:300px;height:52px;overflow:hidden;}
.far_right{margin-left:300px;}
```

---

NOTE: Because this example uses the jQuery library, you must include it on your page -- usually between the DIV tags, like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff in head -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

*If you use a CDN to load jQuery, as in the above example, it is probably already be pre-loaded from other websites.*

---

If you want some fast lessons on jQuery, find free video tuts here:

https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32

or at

https://phpacademy.org/videos/jquery-basics